# Is there a way to remove the owner's read permissions on a file in macOS?

Tags: terminal, permission

Is there any way to take away the owner's permission to read a file in macOS? I know there's no reason to do this but I have to for school and I can't find an answer anywhere.

Removing my write permission works fine but when I try to remove my read permission it automatically gives me read and write permissions back.

As you can see in the console output below, when I use chmod -v -v (extra verbose) it shows the correct permissions it should be changed to, but then when checking afterwards the permissions haven't changed.

```
thijs@Thijss-MacBook-Air-2 week6 % ls -l
total 16
-rw----r--  1 thijs  staff  12 Oct 11 21:10 greeting.txt
-rw-r--r--  1 thijs  staff   0 Oct 11 21:10 hello.txt
-rw-------  1 thijs  staff  15 Oct 11 21:11 weather.txt
thijs@Thijss-MacBook-Air-2 week6 % chmod -v -v u-w weather.txt 
weather.txt: 0100600 [-rw------- ] -> 0100400 [-r-------- ]
thijs@Thijss-MacBook-Air-2 week6 % ls -l 
total 16
-rw----r--  1 thijs  staff  12 Oct 11 21:10 greeting.txt
-rw-r--r--  1 thijs  staff   0 Oct 11 21:10 hello.txt
-r--------  1 thijs  staff  15 Oct 11 21:11 weather.txt
thijs@Thijss-MacBook-Air-2 week6 % chmod -v -v u-r weather.txt 
weather.txt: 0100400 [-r-------- ] -> 0100000 [---------- ]
thijs@Thijss-MacBook-Air-2 week6 % ls -l
total 16
-rw----r--  1 thijs  staff  12 Oct 11 21:10 greeting.txt
-rw-r--r--  1 thijs  staff   0 Oct 11 21:10 hello.txt
-rw-------  1 thijs  staff  15 Oct 11 21:11 weather.txt
```

Comment: This actually should work :-) What is the result of `ls -ald .`? Does it work if you run `chmod 0 weather.txt`?

Comment: Have you try `chmod u-rw weather.txt` At home this is ok for me.

Comment: Pointing out that unless you change the owner of the file, the rights can just be given back as long as the owner has rights on the containing directory.

Comment: sudo chmod u-r filename